# Implement .done().fail() method using winjs.promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, winjs

We are working on windows 8 javascript app and created all the necessary framework to perform operations required. The framework uses jQuery code everywhere.

Now, we have to use the same framework in background tasks as well, but it turned out that jquery is not supported in background tasks as it does not have a valid window object.

As we are using only few methods of jquery, we have decided to ceate a wrapper class which will act as jQuery when used in background tasks.

We are stuck in implementing deferred functionality of jquery using winJs.promise. The problem is that in jQuery we use .done().fail() to handle resolve and reject, where as in winjs.promise, .done() is implemented last in the method queue and does not have a fail method.

We tried implementing fail method but couldn't implement .done().fail().

Could anyone give any suggestion how we can implement it using winjs.promise in a wrapper class?

```
    var $ = (function () {
    function $() {
    }


    $.deferred = function () {
// implement deferred using WinJs.Promise
    }
```

Then use this in framework like this:

```
 function divide(num1, num2) {
    var deferred = $.deferred();

    if (num2 > 0) {
        return deferred.resolve(num1 / num2);
    }
    else {
        return deferred.reject("num2 can't be zero");
    }
}

divide(1, 2).done(function (value) {
    console.log('Anser is:' + value);
}).fail(function (value) {
    console.log('Error: ' + value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The WinJS promise.done method has a second parameter that is the error function.

```
promise.done(onComplete, onError, onProgress);
```

which in your case would be something like:

```
divide(1, 2).done(function (value){
     console.log('Answer is:' + value);  
 },
 function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ' + error);
 });
```

to accomplish this in your own function you can return a promise from your wrapper like this:

```
function divide(num1, num2) {
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (c, e, p) {

        if (num2 > 0) {
            c(num1 / num2);
        }
        else {
            e("num2 can't be zero");
        }
    });
}
```